# jquery post ajax request keeps spinning on firebug without response

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Suddenly today some of my ajax requests have stopped working in some pages and in others they work fine... this is really weird since in Firebug i cant see any error even if i try to debug it from the functions i call... the thing is that firebug's loading image keeps spinning without stopping... also all the parameters are passed correctly the only problem is that i dont get anything back from the request... or if i get i will get it at some pages and at others i will get nothing...

js sample:

```
$(".reply_to_article").click(function(){
    var cct = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name');

    var body = $(this).parent().find("textarea");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/articles/replyToArticle",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            body : body.val(),
            csrf_name : csrf_value
        },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

in replyToArticle function i simply have an `echo 1;`,  which doesn't get returned

Comment: firebug console doesn;t show you what youre server code is responding with  try the network tab in chrome as well.  did you recently change hosts or php versions on your host?

Comment: On Chrome it says "Pending"... it seems to stuck there without stopping or sending back an error message or something...

Comment: sounds like your server is timing out possibly.  if your using ssl on that page it may be that your ssl cert recently expired or it could just be a really expensive db query.  you could always check your server logs to get more details..

Comment: i am actually on my local machine so there is no problem with the ssl since there isnt any... i did check the error log but nothing reported there... also weird... even tried restarting the machine and still nothing changes...

Comment: on your chrome tab where it says pending, click on the name of the method to the left.  then a little view will appear to the right.  click the response tab.  what does that say?

Comment: Do you use session on php?
Then maybe you need to stop the locking session with session_write_close(); right after all session variables were needed...

Answer (score 0):

As a preliminary step, I would try to ensure the POST works for your specified URL. If you have curl installed you can try this:

```
curl -d "testdata1=testvalue1&testdata2=testvalue2" http://www.example.com/articles/replyToArticle
```

and check if you receive your desired response

Curl installation can be found [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Comment: @fxuser if you are echoing a response back then CURL should also display your json response...from your comment, I understand you are not receiving your response but an error page...correct me if I am wrong

Comment: i get an error page probably because i used Codeigniter and it needs the CSRF token value... which when i pass it it still throws me an error "The action you have requested is not allowed" which is due to csrf token